# Is this a quality identification question?

Tags: discussion

[identify-this-sci-fi-action-thriller-actors-could-jump-between-walls](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/1693/identify-this-sci-fi-action-thriller-actors-could-jump-between-walls-and-re-app)

This question is extremely lacking in details.  I want to close it unless the op can add some other details.  Thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the OP doesn't respond to your comment in the next 24 hours, I'd close it.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I am concerned you can go ahead.